# R.layout does not see the XML file

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

In all the code where there is R.layout, when I try to enter the name of the xml file, instead of the usual context file with all the names, it shows something completely unknown to me, like abc__action_menu_layout , although I have not used this.

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.ViewParent
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler
package com.raindrop.tattoofoundler
import androidx.appcompat.R
import androidx.appcompat.R.layout.news_feed_activity
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat
import android.os.Bundle

class Post(
    private val posts: List<Post>,
    private val viewHolderPool: RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Post.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val author: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author)
        val time: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time)
        val genre: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre)
        val photo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): Post.ViewHolder {
        val layoutResId = R.layout.news_feed_activity
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(layoutResId, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: Post.ViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val post = posts[position]

        holder.author.text = post.author
        holder.time.text = "3 минуты назад"
        holder.genre.text = "Anime/DotWork"
        holder.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.sketch5)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = posts.size
}
```

PS - I'm trying to make a RecyclerView to scroll through posts..

XML code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purplebg">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="651dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="388dp"
        android:layout_height="162dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchview"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/test"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="313dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="11dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/intermedium"
        android:text="Говножуйка"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="216dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/interregular"
        android:text="3 минуты назад"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="168dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="221dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/interregular"
        android:text="Anime/DotWork"
        android:textColor="@color/GreyText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="238dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sketch2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="69dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="263dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The file is called news_feed_activity.xml. I tried to remove the dashes - failed, I tried to recreate - failed, I tried to change the file name - failed, I tried to give the full path in the main code - also failed, I've already run out of ideas. Due to the fact that he doesn’t see it, he stupidly doesn’t allow me to insert it into the code to do what I wanted(

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/V1HXUeR - This is what it looks like.

Comment: All errors in the code are due to the fact that r.layout does not see the file IDs or the XML file itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will solve your issue, but the

```
package com.raindrop.tattoofoundler
```

needs to be at the top. Move it to there and it might solve all other issues.

Whenever you see an error it's best to tackle them from top to bottom. You can see that on line 9 it already shows an error

Comment: I rearranged it, no, nothing has changed(

Comment: Also the 9th line shows an error that it cannot detect an XML file feed_news_activity.xml

Comment: @CharonIkh I think you also need to simply delete the two lines with `import androidx.appcompat.R`. You most likely don't want to import those

Comment: YES YES YES, import androidx.appcompat.R It turned out to be superfluous, damn it, I sat on this for an hour, and it turned out to be so stupid, thank you!)